# How to associate Cucumber features to the code itself?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, cucumber, bdd

I am writing cucumber scenarios for my code, and I was wondering if it is really testing the scenarios I've written and then translated to English + RegeX format.

Should I put a require on top of the spet definition file? 
If I leave the test empty or fill in with any valid ruby code, it will pass. Is cucumber working properly the way it should?

I am using Ruby.

Comment: When you execute the cucumber scenario, it will search for the word given in the sceanrio and it will execute the code given in the step definition[.rb files]. If you doesn't have any have code, inside the SD cucumber made the step as passed. It's the behavior in cucumber

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is working as it should.

If you have a scenario that says

```
Given I go to the google website
When I search for flowers
Then I found websites about flowers
```

and You run it, it will stop and tell you that the step def are not defined, and give you examples on how to write them. You can then copy and paste or write them yourself.

If you run it again, it will fail and either say these steps are pending(if you have pending in the step def cause it isnt written yet) or will just error out as an empty test.

You can then put whatever code you want in the step defintion....

So if my given step.."Given I go to the google website"...

has puts "Hello World"

When you run the test, its going to DO the code, and put Hello world, then fail or stop with the pending on the other two steps.

It cant read what your step def says and do that, you have to write the code to make it go to the google website.

Does that make sense?

Comment: Ok, so you let me see if i get this, It doesn't really make a relation between what is said in the step and the code itself, right?

Comment: No, not directly. It will only match what is in the Feature file to what is in the step definitions. What actually HAPPENS in the step, is all up to the code you write.

Answer (score 0):

You can require other libraries such as webdriver and chai to help you write certain commands in the step definition file.

I use cucumber with javascript and the console will correct your step definition if it does not directly match with the feature file steps. I am not sure if this is the case with ruby.

Hope this helps!